# что значит этот синтаксис в css?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Я только начал изучать CSS и у меня возник небольшой ступор в его синтаксисе.

### Например;

```css
#banner .content h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

там где ".content h1" 
и когда они стоят наоборот;

```css
h1 .content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

обьясните в каких случаях и зачем? Не судите строго!)

Comment: почитайте про css селекторы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В css идет обращение от верхних элементов к нижним.

```
#banner .content h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Значит что в элемент с id banner вложен элемент с классом content внутри которого тег h1 (и к этому h1 мы применяем стили).

**Пример:**

```
<div id="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>пример</h1>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Следовательно:

```
h1 .content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Означает что в элемент `h1` вложен другой элемент с классом `content` к которому мы хотим применить стили.

**пример:**

```
<h1>Здесь <span class="content">span внутри h1</span></h1>
```

Comment: @adudnik.ru Вряд ли репа на этом ресурсе значит что либо для hr-ов :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Иметь здесь активный профиль точно лишним не будет. Буду благодарен советам как выглядеть в глазах зарубежных hr агентств ориентированных на IT рынок конфеткой.

Comment: @adudnik.ru это точно не на .ru ресурсе :), хотя откуда мне знать, я работаю на отечественного дядю :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну пока английский доводится до fluent будет русский стак, дальше - будем поглядеть =)

Comment: @adudnik.ru по мне так надо изучать алгоритмы и структуры данных, математику

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мы с тобой об этом уже общались в моем вопросе о том, Какой вуз и специальность с крепкой математикой выбрать. Будет всё, но не сразу =)